# setCanvasClickBehavior is not working for tablets

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using Autodesk Forge Viewer v6.6.4 and have found some problems when I try to setCanvasClickBehavior in a tablet (or Toggle device in Chrome Developer Tools). It seems that this function only works for desktops. In a tablet, this function works as if the code has not been overridden. This is my code:

```
this.viewer.setCanvasClickBehavior({
  click: {
    onObject: ["selectToggle"]
  },
  clickCtrl: {
    onObject: ["selectToggle"]
  }
});
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you certainly haven't done anything wrong and can confirm to be able to reproduce the issue with v6.*.

However this appears to have been fixed in v7.* - tested on v7.4 and it worked as expected.

**UPDATE**

Checking with Engineering to verify the issue and will update this answer later when I hear back.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working in v7.* If you open Chrome Dev Tools and toggle device toolbar, after reloading the page, it'll keep ignoring the new setCanvasClickBehavior configuration. I'm using the iPad preset.

Comment: Hello, Bryan! Is there any progress in this issue?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately - just gave Engineering a nudge and hopefully they could get a fix ready for the next version

Comment: Thanks, Bryan, I'll be waiting

Comment: Has there been a fix for this yet? I need to be able to select multiple objects while on a tablet, but I am running into the same issue. Is there a workaround that could accomplish the same thing?